# How to match all internationalized text?

Tags: regex, r, internationalization

I'm on a search-and-destroy mission for anything Amazon finds distasteful.  In the past I've dealt with this by using `iconv` to convert from "UTF-8" to "latin1", but I can't do that here because it's encoded as "unknown":

```
test <- "Gwena\xeblle M"
> gsub("\xeb","", df[306,"primauthfirstname"] )
[1] "Gwenalle M"
> Encoding(df[306,"primauthfirstname"])
[1] "unknown"
```

So what regex eliminates all the \x## codes?

Comment: Do you happen to know how to easily generate all the \x## codes, outputting them as a character vector? (I need it to test a possible solution).

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Nope but here are a few to test with: `test <- c("\x92","\xe4","\xe1","\xeb")`

Comment: For the record, this is a pretty easy way to generate all characters of the form "\x##": `sapply(0:255, intToUtf8)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this pattern should work:

```
pat <- "[\x80-\xFF]"

test <- c("Gwena\xeblle M", "\x92","\xe4","\xe1","\xeb") 
gsub(pat, "", test, perl=TRUE)
# [1] "Gwenalle M" ""           ""           ""           ""
```

**Explanation:**

It works because the character class `"[\x00-\xFF]"` would match all characters of the form `\x##`. But the first half of those -- the 0th to 127th (or `00`'th to `7F`'th in hex digits) -- are [the ASCII characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). So it's the second half of them -- the 128th to 255th (or `80`'th to `FF`'th in hex mode) -- that you want to search out and destroy.

Comment: This no longer works in the latest version of R, at least on my system: "PCRE pattern compilation error
 'range out of order in character class'".  Will try to debug and report back.

Comment: @AriB.Friedman -- FWIW, this still works for me. I'm using R-3.0.3 (2014-03-06), on Windows, x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit).

Comment: @JoshOBrien Also works for me on my Windows sandbox (3.0.3, 32-bit), but not on my main install (Linux, R 3.0.1, 64-bit). Looking more.

Answer (score 3):

I looped a bit through iconvlist() and found this (among other combinations):

```
test<-"Gwena\xeblle M"
iconv(test,"CP1163","UTF-8")
 [1] "Gwenaëlle M"
```

I realize, this is not what you asked for, but it might be possible to find the correct encoding.