# R accented characters

Tags: r

I am using R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26) with RStudio Version 0.97.168 on Win 7 x64 with locale English_United Kingdom.1252.

I would like to use 'gsub' to replace 'christian grgić' to 'christian grgi[ćc]' (the latter string will later be used as a regular expression to find both the accented and the unaccented version of the name).

However, R does not seem to recognize the ć as accented c. This code

```
name <- "christian grgić"
gsub("ć","[cć]",name)
```

gives this output

```
[1] "[cc]hristian grgi[cc]"
```

rather than what I want:

```
[1] "christian grgi[cć]"
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: `Encoding` may be a starting place.

Comment: See this question for hints on `regex`ing with international text: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369668/how-to-match-all-internationalized-text

Comment: Thanks, but encoding is beyond my understanding at the moment. My system default encoding seems to be ISO8859-1 (what I get from localeToCharset). If I save my script with this encoding, the accented c is lost next time I open it. So I save with encoding UTF-8 (RStudio provides this option) and reopen next time again with encoding UTF-8. Then, however, if I run `name <- "christian grgić"` and then `Encoding(name)` I get "unknown" and I cannot set any encoding to the string.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Encoding(name) <- "UTF-8"
gsub("ć","[cć]",name)
#[1] "christian grgi[cć]"
```

Note this is the info I get for local from sessionInfo():

```
> locale: [1]
> en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
```

Comment: this solution depends in the local session info?

Comment: Thanks, as I have just added above, the first line of your code does not work for me. What I get from sessionInfo() is `locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252`

Comment: The phrase "does not work" admits of many possible interpretations.

Comment: If I run `Encoding(name)` I get `Unknown` as a result. And if I try to set an encoding like in your first line of code, and then run `Encoding(name)` again, the result is the same (`Unknown`). I cannot assign any encoding to `name`. That's what I meant.

Comment: The op's problem is windows specific.